# How to find out if an X window is mapped (visible) or not?

Tags: x11, xorg

I use xdotool to map/unmap a set of dock-like windows. Now, xdotool doesn't come with a toggle (map/unmap) command, neither does it come with doing the same operation with multiple windows at once. So I'm trying to perform the clubbed toggle using a script. I need a way to find out if the most recent operation was a map or an unmap.

Comment: `xwininfo -id windowid | grep 'Map State'`

Comment: `xwininfo` can also can also find windows by `-name`. Not by class name, though.

Comment: @mosvy, thanks. Specifically, I need xdotool to toggle the "Map State", that is, unmap the window if it is currently mapped and vice versa. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: There probably is a way, by using `search --classname` twice, once with `--onlyvisible` and once without it, or by chaining commands, but I was never able to come to terms with xdotools syntax, quirks and bugs ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a way, files can be thought of as a simple way to store global variables, global so that it is visible from everywhere. So the state (mapped/unmapped) can be stored as a string in a file.

Not the most elegant thing, but this script (named xctl) should do for now.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

# This file serves as a global variable value holder showing if the windows are mapped or not.
state=/tmp/state

for process in ${@:1}; do
    case $1 in
        (show) xdotool search --class $process windowmap %@ windowraise %@;;
        (hide) xdotool search --onlyvisible --class $process windowunmap %@;;
        (*) break;;
    esac
done

[[ $1 == toggle ]] && {
    [[ -f $state ]] && [[ `cat $state` == show ]] && xctl hide ${@:1} || xctl show ${@:1}
} || echo $1 > $state
```

To toggle a set of windows, run `xctl toggle window1 window2 ...`.

The script must reside in the shell's path.